UMP test for Bernoulli distribution one sample
Given $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1\}$, $\Theta= \{ 1/2,1/4 \}$ and $\mathcal{P}= \{ B(\theta):\theta \in \Theta \}$, I am trying to construct an UMP test of size $\alpha \in (0,1)$ for
$$H_0: \theta=1/4 \,H_1: \theta=1/2$$
I figured to evaluate $$L_{1/2,\ 1/4}(x)=\frac{f_{1/2}(x)}{f_{1/4}(x)}=\begin{cases} 2 & x = 1 \\\ \frac{2}{3} & \, x=0\end{cases} $$
Using this I tried to solve for $c \geq 0$ such that:
$$\varphi(x)= \mathbb{1}(L_{1/2,\ 1/4}(x)>c)$$
and $E_{1/4}(\varphi)=\alpha$, so I have a Neyman-Pearson Test which by NP-Lemma would be UMP.
But evaluating the expected value got me:
$\begin{align*} 
E_{1/4}(\varphi) &= 
\mathbb{P}_{1/4}(L_{1/2,\ 1/4}(x)>c) \\ &=  \mathbb{P}_{1/4}(L_{1/2,\ 1/4}(X)>c, X=0) + \mathbb{P}_{1/4}(L_{1/2,\ 1/4}(X)>c, X=1) \\  &= \mathbb{P}(\frac{2}{3}>c)\frac{3}{4}+ \mathbb{P}(2>c)\frac{1}{4} \\ &= \mathbb{1}(\frac{2}{3}>c)\frac{3}{4}+\mathbb{1}(\frac{2}{3}>c)\frac{1}{4} \stackrel{!}{=} \alpha
\end{align*} $
Here I don't know how to proceed, to solve for c.
I would be glad about a tip and/or pointer!

One flip of a coin is not really enough to distinguish between the two hypotheses.  You essentially have three possible strategies: $2 \le c$ in which case you never reject $H_0$ and $\alpha=0$, $\frac23 \le c \lt 2$ in which case  you reject $H_0$ if $x=1$ but not if $x=0$ so $\alpha = \frac14$, or $c \lt \frac23$  in which case you always reject $H_0$ and $\alpha=1$.

@Henry, yes this what I essentially concluded, but I thought I missed something. Thank you for your insight! I will try to construct an UMP test, for any $\alpha$, with more than one sample.
